# Finding the directory path

Tags: c++, windows

I'm making a windows application, and right now I can find the path for a file when I click open, but how would I be able to find the directory path? For example, if user selects "file.txt", then I want to get the path of "file.txt".(Its location on the disk). I'm using ATL/WTL, and VS 2013.

```
OPENFILENAME m_ofn;

BOOL m_bOpenFileDialog = true;  // TRUE for file open, FALSE for file save
TCHAR m_szFileTitle[_MAX_FNAME];// contains file title after return
TCHAR m_szFileName[_MAX_PATH];  // contains full path name after return

memset(&m_ofn, 0, sizeof(m_ofn));
m_szFileName[0] = _T('\0');
m_szFileTitle[0] = _T('\0');

m_ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(m_ofn);

m_ofn.lpstrFile = m_szFileName;
m_ofn.nMaxFile = _MAX_PATH;
m_ofn.lpstrDefExt = _T("bmp");
m_ofn.lpstrFileTitle = (LPTSTR)m_szFileTitle;
m_ofn.nMaxFileTitle = _MAX_FNAME;

m_ofn.Flags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | 
              OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | OFN_EXPLORER | 
              OFN_ENABLEHOOK | OFN_ENABLESIZING;

m_ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("Image Files (*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpe;*.gif;*.tga)\0*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpe;*.gif;*.tga\0All Files\0*.*\0");
m_ofn.hInstance = ModuleHelper::GetResourceInstance();
m_ofn.lpfnHook = NULL;
m_ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;

BOOL bRet;
bRet = ::GetOpenFileName(&m_ofn);
char gcd;
gcd = GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(m_ofn), m_szFileName);
m_view.Report("Filename = %S\n", m_szFileName);
```

Comment: This is not c it is c++.

Comment: It's a mixture of both

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "how would I be able to find the directory path"?

Comment: It is no valid C. Do not use C tag for C++ code.

Comment: Also note that it is `bool`, not `BOOL` (that is neither a standard C nor a C++ type).

Comment: @Olaf: BOOL is a winapi #define and what many Win32 functions return.

Comment: @Olaf It's a Win32. And this works for finding a file path, I'm asking for help for directory path.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Ok, but would that not be `TRUE`/`FALSE` then?

Comment: @cpp_prog if I were to click on a directory what's the path for that directory. The code I have clearly finds the path for the file. But if I have no files in that directory I want to be able to find the correct path

Comment: @WakkaDroid It sounds like you're looking for the [SHBrowseForFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx) function (or on Vista or later, `IFileDialog`).

Comment: @Olaf: Could you take your crusade elsewhere, please? If you find that a question has inappropriate tags, use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31820742/edit) link. This need not produce as much noise as it usually does with you. Thank you.

Comment: Your call to [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx) is pretty much bogus. You're passing an unrelated value as the *nBufferLength* parameter. The return value is not of type `char` either. It's a `DWORD`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm still really new to windows development and it's very confusing to me on how to set up IFileDialog, I had a coworker help me out a lot with this part. any good places where I can see good IFileDialog examples?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485843(v=vs.85).aspx for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `lpstrFile` member of your `m_ofn` object contains the full path of `file.txt`. You can then remove the trailing `\file.txt` part with [`PathCchRemoveFileSpec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707092(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: [PathCchRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707092.aspx) is available starting with Windows 8. For versions prior to Windows 8 you can consider using the (deprecated) [PathRemoveFileSpec function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx).

Comment: @llnspectable I tried that but it doesn't seem to be working what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @WakkaDroid: We're not psychic. It **might** be a good question on its own, but before you post that new question please make a minimal example. Can you get `PathCchRemoveFileSpec` working if you give it a hardcoded `C:\Test\file.txt`  input? Obviously that example should compile and run. But TBH you'll probably find your bug when you're stripping down your current code to that minimal example.